# Java project look for C++ projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, project, eclipse-cdt

Is it possible to change the default appearance of C++-projects in Eclipse? I quite like the way how in Java-Projects packets (which are folders on the harddisk) are displayed (com.sth...)

How can I apply this to my C++-projects? I would like the different subfolders displayed in a similar structure to the one used for JAVA-projects.

Is there a programmatical solution for an Eclipse plugin using CDT or is there a setting in the project explorer I have overseen?

Comment: Obviously there is nothing that suits my needs so I have implemented the missing Eclipse view myself...